# Quadcopter force/torques duty cycle conversion

Tags: control, quadcopter, pwm

after having been determined my control loops for my quadcopter project, I'm going to determine the motor commands (PWM duty cycle) from the motor forces/torques. I was following the guidelines of [this document](http://rwbclasses.groups.et.byu.net/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=quadrotor:beardsquadrotornotes.pdf) but when I was trying to do the inverse of the matrix M (page 17) it has determinant equal to 0. The procedure is correct? Anyone can suggest me some other link for doing this conversion? I have searched in the Internet but I haven't found so much about that. Thanks
The part of the document that I'm referring is the following:
[image]

Comment: As a comment, because I don't have an answer, I verified that M is not invertible. In the section just before where you quote, the author states motor speed is proportional to PWM duration, and lift (vertical force) is proportional to speed squared, so it would seem as though lift (force) were proportional to PWM squared. It's a shame it looks like this paper was authored by a university professor and impossible math is stated like it's a fact.

Comment: ok thanks @Chuck, I'm trying to do the same thing in another way, if you want give a look to my new question http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/quadcopter-pid-output-and-duty-cycle-conversion

Answer (score 1):

Each axis input is a linear combination of the control input and the sensor (gyros and accelerometers) for that axis.  Not necessarily answering your question, but add this to your matrix